# JakartaEE with Wildfly and JBoss configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I want to start my first "Hello World" project using JakartaEE with JBoss/WildFly
but i have the error that I can't solve.

After start my project i have the error:

```
[2022-12-03 12:17:58,968] Artifact servletLearn:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 9990
Detected server http port: 8080
Failed to read or configure the org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.lambda$validate$2(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:122)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.WrappedAction.execute(WrappedAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:118)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:336)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:289)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:546)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:170)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.19.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:132)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:446)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:395)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:383)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:431)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:444)
```

The configuration:

[image]

Please tell me if i should add pictures of other configuration files

UPDATE:

I had to change access to files and folders:

```
/opt/wildfly-27.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/
/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/
server.log in /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/
```

But now i have the error:

```
00:26:19,038 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-management is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management]"]
}
00:26:19,040 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
    ("file-audit-log" => "local-audit")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.security.security-event-listener.local-audit" => "WFLYELY00004: Unable to start the service.
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly-27.0.0.Final/standalone/log/audit.log (Permission denied)"}}
00:26:19,088 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
    ("properties-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.security.security-realm.ApplicationRealm" => "WFLYELY00017: Property file referenced in properties-realm does not exist: /opt/wildfly-27.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application-users.properties (Permission denied)"}}
00:26:19,088 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
    ("properties-realm" => "ManagementRealm")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.security.security-realm.ManagementRealm" => "WFLYELY00017: Property file referenced in properties-realm does not exist: /opt/wildfly-27.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/mgmt-groups.properties (Permission denied)"}}
00:26:19,090 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0459: Triggering roll back due to missing management services.
00:26:19,090 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-management is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management]"]
}
00:26:19,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
00:26:19,105 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
00:26:19,106 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
00:26:19,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
00:26:19,106 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
00:26:19,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
00:26:19,112 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8443
00:26:19,112 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
00:26:19,113 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.3.0.Final stopping
00:26:19,134 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details. - Server configuration file in use: standalone.xml
00:26:19,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 27.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 19.0.0.Final) stopped in 5ms
Disconnected from server
```

What should i change/add in standalone.xml to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you have permissions issues with audit.log

Comment: It looks like some files still don't have the right access permissions (`mgmt-groups.properties`, `application-users.properties`, etc.). Double check the permissions for all contents of the `standalone` folder.